# Improving a mysql/php advanced search form

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a mysql/php search form this morning which uses checkboxes to set a parameter for color. Currently, grabbing my search terms via get, using if statements to qualify them, putting them in an array, and imploding that array using AND to build my mysql query. This work very well, however I run into problems when I need my sql statement to use multiple iterations of the if statement. Here is the code. I will explain in more detail to clarify below the code.

```
//Color

if (isset($_GET['white'])){
    $white = $_GET['white'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($white)."'";
    }

if (isset($_GET['red'])){
    $red = $_GET['red'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($red)."'";
}

if (isset($_GET['blue'])){
    $blue = $_GET['blue'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($blue)."'";
}

if (isset($_GET['colorless'])){
    $colorless = $_GET['colorless'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($colorless)."'";
}

if (isset($_GET['green'])){
    $green = $_GET['green'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($green)."'";
}

if (isset($_GET['black'])){
    $black = $_GET['black'];
    $where[] = "color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($black)."'";
}

//GLUE ALL THE SEARCH FIELDS TOGETHER WITH AN IMPLODE STATEMENT

if(count($where)) {
    $query.= 'SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
}
```

As you can see, if for instance, the 'white' checkbox is checked, my mysql query will read:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE color = 'W'
```

Where I run into problems is the following. What do I do if I need to run a search with multiple colors? So for instance on my form if I check both WHITE and RED, how do I modify my search to read like this:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE color = 'WR'
```

Any help would be appreciated as always. Kind Regards

Sour Jack

Comment: `color = 'WR'` or this `color = 'W || color = 'R'`

Comment: Don't use this deprecated API

Answer (score 3):

How about using `IN`?

```
$allowed = ['white', 'red', 'green', 'black'];
$found   = [];
$clause  = '';

foreach ($allowed as $a) {
  if (isset($_GET[$a])) {
    $found[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$a]);
  }
}

$clause = '';
if (count($found)) {
   $clause = sprintf(' WHERE color IN (%s)', implode(',', $found));
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM inventory' . $clause;
```

Note: [SELECT * is evil.](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-*-is-evil)

Also, the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and is due for removal in future releases. It's recommended to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: pls edit and tell OP to use pdo or mysqli. After all `mysql_*` is big evil .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Color

if (isset($_GET['white'])){
    $white = $_GET['white'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($white);
    }

if (isset($_GET['red'])){
    $red = $_GET['red'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($red);
}

if (isset($_GET['blue'])){
    $blue = $_GET['blue'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($blue);
}

if (isset($_GET['colorless'])){
    $colorless = $_GET['colorless'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($colorless);
}

if (isset($_GET['green'])){
    $green = $_GET['green'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($green);
}

if (isset($_GET['black'])){
    $black = $_GET['black'];
    $where[] = mysql_real_escape_string($black);
}

if(count($where)) {
    $query.= "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE color IN ('".implode("','", $where)."')";

}
```

Comment: This sort of works but I wasn't clear enough in my description of what I'm trying to accomplish. So the in statement will give me results that are White, or Blue etc. But I also need results that have a combination of colors such as White AND Blue. Those colors are listed in the database as WB or BW for instance.

Comment: @SourJack Update your question with set of data in **inventory** table.